# Put a view inside my Map Annotation, and change this view when touched

Tags: iphone, ios, mapkit, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I insert a mapView in my app, and insert annotations, but he put one pin in the places and when i touch the pins appear my annotation with one title and one line of text, i made this using one basic tutorial

Now i need to change this annotation to have a image, a button and a name, or just one image, i need that every coordinate i mark to have one annotation be like this image and don't that red pin:
[image]

and when i touch this annotation, this have to change to this: (animation will be nice here)
[image]

and when i touch this red button i will go to another view, but i'm in trouble with this, i'm looking for tutorials, but nothing that really help me, but i'm even don't know how to start this.